# How to design a modular content block system

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I'm trying to build a blogging system which enables users to add and arrange content blocks to their posts consisting of either text-type, image-type, video-type etc.

I'm considering a `Post` model with a `has_many` relationship to a `ContentBlock` model. But after this logic, I get stuck. A `ContentBlock` can be either a text-block, an image, an image carousel, a quote etc.

I have two questions for this problem:

1. What is best practice regarding database design for this type of setup?
2. How would the building of the content blocks look like in the view layer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using single table inheritance (STI) to delegate the logic of association of content. In that way, a `Post` can have many content blocks of different types e.g. `TextBlock`, `ImageBlock` etc.

The content blocks in turn may be associated with varying attachments. A `TextBlock` has one `TextAttachment` and an `ImageBlock` has one `ImageAttachment` etc.

A column on the `ContentBlock` model allows the user to arrange the blocks to their liking and when I render the HTML for a `Post`, I just use a partial depending on the type of `ContentBlock`.

**models/post.rb**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :content_blocks
    has_many :image_blocks, source: 'ContentBlock', as: :resource
    has_many :image_slider_blocks, source: 'ContentBlock', as: :resource
    has_many :text_blocks, source: 'ContentBlock', as: :resource

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :content_blocks, allow_destroy: true
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :image_blocks, allow_destroy: true
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :image_slider_blocks, allow_destroy: true
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :text_blocks, allow_destroy: true
end
```

**models/content_block.rb**

```
class ContentBlock < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :post
end
```

**models/image_slider_block.rb**

```
class ImageSliderBlock < ContentBlock
    has_many :image_attachments, dependent: :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :image_attachments, allow_destroy: true
end
```

**views/posts/show.html.erb**

```
<%= @post.content_blocks.order(:row_order).each do |block| %>
    <%= render block.type.underscore, block: block %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest you the following:

add a field to Post called type_id:integer, create a model called Type with an name:string.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :type

  ## is it text?
  def text?
    type.id == Type.by_type('text')
  end


end

class Type < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post

  scope :by_type, ->(type) { where(name: type) }
end
```

this is an example how you can implement it extend it with more method to make the validation more easier.